# Free 3 0f 9 Extended Barcode fonts

Tags: fonts

I am looking to add the tab caharcter into a barcode that will contain a username & (tab) & and the password. Does anyone out there know how, or knows of a site I can go to with the information on it. Thanks

Comment: Is this really a better choice than yellow stickies all around your desk? ;)

Comment: That is cute, but seriously my boss got me a new barcode scanner so I don't what him to see all my passwords! HaHa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I is the code for tab.

Check [this table](http://www.idautomation.com/code39faq.html#ExtendedCode39) out for what appear to be standard functions (last column) for 3 of 9 (or Code 39 as it is called on that site.  I'm assuming that they're mostly equivalent.)

Answer (score 1):

For full ascii 3 of 9 encodes a tab as a 2 character $H, so if you're trying to enter this with a scanner you have to depend on how the scanner driver handles the 2 character codes.

Check out the
[wikipedia code 3 of 9 entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39)